# SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The query:

```
Explain SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 2
```

Displays the field names of the given table. Can anyone explain this syntax? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is MySQL Utility Statement - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Comment: Actually SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 2 could return records if a column was called 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EXPLAIN is MySQL Utility Statement

The `EXPLAIN` statement can be used either as a way to obtain information about how MySQL executes a statement.

When you precede a `SELECT` statement with the keyword `EXPLAIN`, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the query execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information about how tables are joined and in which order.

In short, EXPLAIN statement is used to investigate how MySQL is executing the query.

Your statement generates following output -

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Impossible WHERE
```

As you can see under column `Extra` it is returning `Impossible WHERE` text. It means that MySQL has identified that it will result in zero rows.

Likewise other columns will help you to identify INDEXES being used and other useful information.

For more information please refer - [EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)

Answer (score 5):

You're returning no results, because `1 = 2` is false.  (There are no records that match that `WHERE` clause, so you just get the table headings, and no records.)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I confess that I didn't even see the word "Explain" *in* your query, so I didn't even try to answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since 1 is not equal to 2, the results of the query will be empty.  i.e., for no row in any conceivable output, will the expression 1 = 2  be true.  So all you get is the column headers, (the field names),  and no actual data rows...

Answer (score 2):

the query will yield no results because the where condition is false... the logical condition of 1 = 2 stands false in case the reference of 1, 2 is to column headers and yield results.

Answer (score 1):

`explain` is used to see the execution plan of a query. If you add it at the beginning of your query you can see which indexes are used for the select and so forth.

So the query won't display any results. If you remove `explain` from your statement and just execute the  `select ...` then you will get the results of your query. In your case that will be no results since `1=2` is never `true`.

See [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an empty set (you project column names and data in column, but where clause filters everything so you just see column names).

You can achieve the same thing with a couple of characters less.

```
select top 0 * from TABLE
```

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Answer (score -3):

SELECT *(all tables) FROM TABLE(table name here is table) WHERE 1(table's name 1) (equals) = 2

e.g. show all tables from table's table where table named 1 equals to 2.

Cheers.,

Comment: Um... this is nothing right... because `1 != 2`.